# Change the protection of a workbook based on save location / filename

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have a workbook which I have marked as final, but which I want users to be able to make a copy of which *isn't final*. However I can't figure out how to do this.

I was thinking of putting the following code in the `ThisWorkbook`-module of the workbook, but I am hesitant since without saving the workbook again the changes made won't stick, and if I put in a `ThisWorkbook.Save` there the workbook will be saved twice (at least, I think I'd have to disable events before saving again?) every time the user saves the workbook.

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
    If ThisWorkbook.FullName = "<full name of the original>" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Final = True
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Final = False
    End If
End Sub
```

Do you guys have any suggestions for a more elegant solution?

Answer (score 0):

Add this function in a module to determine if the workbook is a final workbook :

```
Option Explicit

Public Function IsAWorkbookFinal() As Boolean

    Dim wb As ThisWorkbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook

    Dim final_wb As String
    final_wb = "C:\test\final\test_wb_save.xlsm" 'adapt with fullname of final workbook

        If wb.FullName = final_wb Then
            IsAWorkbookFinal = True
        Else
            IsAWorkbookFinal = False
        End If

End Function
```

Comment: Do you get the new location / name of a workbook before the event you use triggers? I am pretty sure you don't which is why I used `Workbook_AfterSave` instead.

Comment: Oups, you're right. Need to change to afterSave and then you can use the function.

Comment: If I do that, what is the benefit of your approach, instead of just doing the shorter test against `ThisWorkbook.FullName`?

Comment: You can change to .FullName if you want, the result will be the same.

Comment: @eirikdaude Does the function do what you need ?